# Why is a bit-wise AND necessary to check if a bit is set?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I am learning a backtrack problem with memoization using bit-mask.

When checking if the `i`'th bit is set in a bit-mask, all the solutions I have come across are doing `(mask >> i) & 1`. I was wondering, why is the `& 1` necessary? Isn't `(mask >> i)` a 1 when the `i`'th bit is set, and a 0 when the bit is not set? That already translate into `true` and `false`.

Comment: _"Isn't (mask >> i) a 1 when the ith bit is set"_  No.  `255 >> 1` will not produce a `1`.

Comment: `2 >> 1` is `1`, but `6 >> 1` is `3` and `4 >> 1` gives `2`.

Comment: You could use `x%2` as an alternative to `x&1`. So bitwise-and isn't strictly necessary.

Comment: The purpose of using `binary AND` is to remove all the unwanted bits before other operations are performed.  If you are lucky, some processors have an actual instruction that tests specific bits, and your compiler emits these instructions.

Comment: Another way to test the `i`'th bit is `mask & (1 << i)`

Comment: Let's say mask has a binary value `111000` and `i` has a value `2`.   `mask >> i` will be `001110` which is a non-zero value with last bit clear.    `mask >> i` will therefore test `true` but `(mask >> i) & 1` tests specifically if that last bit is set, so will test `false`.

Comment: Why aren't you using `std::bitset` or `std::vector<bool>`?#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(mask >> i)` cannot eliminate the higher bits.

For example, when `mask = 5` (`101` in binary) and `i = 1`, the value of `(mask >> i)` is `2`. This evaluated as `true`, but the 2nd lowest bit is `0`, so you fail to check the bit correctly.

Therefore, `& 1` is necessary to eliminate the higher bits and check one specified bit correctly.

Answer (score 1):

For example, if you want to check bit 0 for the mask `0b10` then the expression `mask >> 0` yields the same value `0b10`, that is not equal to `0`. However, its bit 0 is equal to `0`. So you need to write `( mask >> 0 ) & 1`, or in general `( mask >> i ) & 1`.

That is, higher bits that precede the i-th bit can be `1`. Thus the expression `mask >> i` does not change their values. So the value of the expression can be unequal to `0` though the i-th bit itself is equal to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `(mask >> i)` keeps all the bits from the i-th. That means, if either the i-th, (i+1)-th, etc. is set, then it'll evaluate to `true` in an `if-expression`.